# Release local variable to a window scoped variable?

Tags: javascript

I have a global variable NS which I can access from the console as such:

```
NS.some_func();
```

NS is populated using a method called `extendSafe()`

```
some_scope.extendSafe = function (o1, o2) {
    var key;
    for (key in o2) {
        if (o2.hasOwnProperty(key) && o1.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            throw "naming collision: " + key;
        }
        o1[key] = o2[key];
    }
    return o1;
};
```

This is used by setting up a public scope called `$P` and then copying over to the global scope `NS` once all the $P methods have been defined.

I want to to it this way so I can verify that I'm not writing over any properties.

This worked well until I tried to save a local variable to `$P` for later copying to `NS`.  Because the interpreter does not know that $P will be "released" to the window scope, it does not know to keep the local variable active.  So I can not use my safeExtend method.

I verified this was the issue by doing a direct copy as such:

```
NS.local = local;
```

I can now access NS.local from the console.

However if I copy it over as I wish to do:

```
$P.local = local;
extendSafe(NS, $P);
```

The local variable is not available.

How can I safely release it, i.e. using `safeExtend()`?

**Code Snippet**

Issue is commented as

`// hacked needs a fix`

```
    $P.machine = function (obj) {
        var pipe,
            data_send,
            ajax_type,
            wait_animation,
            set;
        wait_animation = document.getElementById('wait_animation');
        set = false;
        pipe = NS.makePipe(obj);
        if ($R.Parsel[pipe.model] === undefined) {
            return;
        }
        time('start');
        if ($R.Parsel[pipe.model].hasOwnProperty("pre")) {
            pipe = $R.Parsel[pipe.model].pre(pipe);
        } else {
            return;
        }
        if (pipe.form_data) {
            ajax_type = 'multi';
            var form_data = pipe.form_data;
            delete pipe.form_data;
            form_data.append("pipe", JSON.stringify(pipe));
            data_send = form_data;
        } else {
            ajax_type = 'post';
            data_send = 'pipe=' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(pipe));
        }
        if (pipe.state === true) {
            time('middle');
            if (wait_animation) {
                set = true;
                wait_animation.style.opacity = 1;
            }
            NS.ajax({
                type:     ajax_type,
                url:      NS.Reg.get('path') + NS.Reg.get('path_ajax'),
                data:     data_send,
                callback: function (pipe_string_receive) {
                    var pass_prefix = pipe_string_receive.slice(0, 3),
                        times;
                    if (wait_animation && set) {
                        wait_animation.style.opacity = 0;
                    }
                    if (pass_prefix === '|D|') {
                        NS.log('|DEBUG| ' + pipe_string_receive.slice(3));
                    } else if (pass_prefix === '|A|') {
                        time('middle');
                        pipe = JSON.parse(pipe_string_receive.slice(3));
                        if ($R.Parsel[pipe.model].hasOwnProperty("post")) {
                            pipe = $R.Parsel[pipe.model].post(pipe);
                            times = time('finish');
                            pipe.time.pre = times[0];
                            pipe.time.transit = times[1];
                            pipe.time.post = times[2];

                            // works but hacked needs a fix

                            NS.last = pipe;

                            // will not exendSafe()

                            $P.last = pipe;

                        } else {
                            return;
                        }
                    } else {
                        throw "<No 'A' or 'D'>" + pipe_string_receive;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

I see you've solved the problem, but I have a feeling that there's something you're misunderstanding about JavaScript:

> This worked well until I tried to save a local variable to $P for later copying to NS. Because the interpreter does not know that $P will be "released" to the window scope, it does not know to keep the local variable active. So I can not use my safeExtend method.
>
> I verified this was the issue by doing a direct copy as such:
>
> ```
> NS.local = local;
> ```
>
> I can now access NS.local from the console.
>
> However if I copy it over as I wish to do:
>
> ```
> $P.local = local;
> extendSafe(NS, $P);
> ```
>
> The local variable is not available.
>
> How can I safely release it, i.e. using `safeExtend()?`

This doesn't make sense. JavaScript is very good at keeping track of references to objects. If there are any references to an object, it won't garbage collect the object. I have no idea what it could mean to "release an object to the window scope". There isn't really any such concept, just objects and references to them.

I tried looking through your original code, but there's a lot of code there that isn't related to the problem. If you were to simplify it to a minimal test case, I'll bet a simpler solution would become evident.

I do see one issue in your smaller snippet above. You defined your `extendSafe()` function as `some_scope.extendSafe()`, but here you're calling it with a plain `extendSafe()` call and no reference to `some_scope`. Did it actually call the function? Is this just a typo in the smaller example?

Of course, if you're just happy to have found a solution and want to move on, that's quite understandable! I just have a strong feeling that there's extra code here that you don't need.